# CloudWatch Metrics for Application Load Balancer on a grafana dashboard

Tags: grafana, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-eks, aws-application-load-balancer

I have configured a kubernetes deployments in a eks cluster , the deployment contains 2 replicas , the 2 replicas are behind an Application Load balancer , I am trying to implement a grafana dashboard  that shows if my application is up .

I have already configured CloudWatch as a datasource for grafana , any toughts on witch cloudwatch metrics I should use for this ?

I have used the HealthyHostCount metric , but sometimes one of my 2 replicas get down but my app is still accessible since the other replica is up , so I am looking o a ALB cloudwatch metric related ( Helathchecks on the ALB .. )

Answer (score 0):

There is no CloudWatch metric for that. But if you have proper healthchek implementation, then you may use `HealthyHostCount` with  [CloudWatch metric math](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/using-metric-math.html) and calculate it, e. g. if HealthyHostCount is 0 then your AppAvailability is 0, otherwise 1. CloudWatch metric math is supported also by Grafana.